# Incorrect xpath query

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to aggregate the club phone numbers from this html.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="padded">
       <ul class="state-list">
       <ul class="state-city-list">
          <li class="jumper">
        <div class="clubinfo">
            <div class="clubaddress">123 West Palm Blvd</div>
            <div class="clubphone">5555551123</div>
        </div>
          </li>
       </ul>                    
       <ul class="state-city-list">
          <li class="jumper">
        <div class="clubinfo">
            <div class="clubaddress">456 West Palm Blvd</div>
            <div class="clubphone">5555555456</div>
        </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="state-city-list">
          <li class="jumper">
        <div class="clubinfo">
            <div class="clubaddress">789 West Palm Blvd</div>
            <div class="clubphone">5555555789</div>
        </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="state-city-list">
          <li class="jumper">
        <div class="clubinfo">
            <div class="clubaddress">213 West Palm Blvd</div>
            <div class="clubphone">5555555213</div>
        </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my PHP Code:

```
    $htmlfile='phonecontents';
    $xml=new DOMDocument();
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
    $xml->loadHTMLFile($htmlfile);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);
    //$elm = $xpath->query('/div[@id="content"]/div[@class="container"]/div[@class="padded"]/ul[@class="state-list"]/li[@class="jumper"]/div[@class="clubinfo"]/div[@class="clubphone"]');
    $elm = $xpath->query('/div[@id="content"]/div[@class="clubinfo"]/div[@class="clubphone"]');
    if(!is_null($elm)){
      var_dump($elm);
      foreach($elm as $el){
        echo $el->nodeValue."\n";
      }
    } else {
      echo "NO DATA FOUND \n";
    }
```

I'm not quite sure because i'm new to xpath but I am unable to get my data correctly. If you look at the php code you can see i tried with 2 different queries neither seemed to work.

Comment: `//div[@class="clubphone"]` should work. You need to youse `//` in the begin to get all the html and inspect it using xpath

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$elm = $xpath->query('//div[@id="content"]//div[@class="clubinfo"]/div[@class="clubphone"]');
```

Using one slash means "direct child of", using two slashes means "any descendant of".